# F# pattern matching with DataGridColumn.Visibility

Tags: .net, f#, enums, pattern-matching

I'm encountering a situation where I'm using pattern matching for determining the visibility property of a column.  `System.Windows.Visibility` has two fields,  `Visibility.Visible` and `Visibility.Collapsed`.  Can enyone tell me why the following code:

```
let colItem = myDataGrid.Columns.Item 1
     chkBox.IsChecked <-
          match colItem.Visibility with
               | Visibility.Visible -> new Nullable<bool>(true)
               | Visibility.Collapsed -> new Nullable<bool>(false)
```

generates the follwing warning:

> Incomplete pattern matches on this
>   expression. For example, the value
>   '2uy' may indicate a case not covered
>   by the pattern(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory a value of type Visibility can be something other than Visible or Collapsed because .net enums allow any value of the underlying integral type as a value for the enum type (to allow things like ORing enums).

Comment: Right, .NET enums are thin facades over integer types, and can take on any value of the underlying integer type.

Comment: This is correct.  For instance, `(LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue 2uy : Visibility)` will give you a value of type `Visibility` which is neither `Visible` nor `Collapsed`, just as the compiler warns about.